# White spaces in Web a page when zooming out

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

I have a fixed header with 44 pixels height, a content that has 89% div and a footer 6% division. When my browser is on 100% zoom its looks okay, and when I'm zooming out a white spaces appear before the footer section.

I try to changed the header's height to 5% but our requirements must be header should be fixed to 44 pixels.

Question: 
Is it possible to have a static header and dynamic content with footer?

Comment: Can you provide a zoomed and not-zoomed image? I sort of see (in my head what you are saying), but not enough to be helpful.

Comment: I bet there is absolutely no requirement on how the page should look when at any zoom level other than 100%. Because, guess what? This zoom function is something browsers thought would be useful for users. This feature is not regulated in any way and each browser implemented it as they saw fit. Being non-standard, it can't be required, as you have no means of controlling (or knowing) how browsers zoom. It's above page level - in most of them you can't even determine the current level of zoom.

Comment: Hi bench, I found a way to get the size of the content using body's height - (header height + footer height). I use Jquery to automatic resize depends on the browser size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS calc() function.

If you want to have static 44px header and you know that footer should be 6%, then just set your content: 100% - 6%(footer) = 94% - 44px (header).

So using calc():

```
content {
  width: calc(94% - 44px);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

header {
  height: 44px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

main {
  height: calc(94% - 44px);
  background: yellow;
}

footer {
  height: 6%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks but i found a better way and it looks like this.
 
var h = $(window).height(), w = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function(){

    var nh = $(window).height(), nw = $(window).width();
     // compare the corresponding variables.
    h = nh; w = nw; // update h and w;
});

Comment: Using window.resize function i can automatically set the content width depends on the windows size and the difference from the sum of header and content.